# Strange "No line to end error" from \newchapter{} Thesis Formatting

Tags: line-breaking, chapters, thesis

I'm using a document class from my University, {urithesis} and I'm receiving some strange errors I can't seem to clear up - I was hoping someone might have some experience with similar issues.

This is my error:

```
! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.
See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type H <return> for immediate help.
...
l.33 \newchapter{chapter1}
Your command was ignored.
Type I <command> <return> to replace it with another command,
or <return> to continue without it.
```

Pretty standard error. I looked for the usual culprits (\, \newlines, etc.) but couldn't find a cause.

This is my main thesis document:
    \documentclass{urithesis}

```
%% See http://www.ele.uri.edu/info/thesis/guide for details.
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

%% This makes the pdf file contain active links for all references,
%% urls, the table of contents, etc., and creates a pdf menu.
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0},plainpages=false,pdfpagelabels]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
%% This should be the title of this dissertation/thesis.
\title{GPS Spoofing Detection and using Multiple Antennas and Individual Space Vehicle      Pseudoranges}
%% This should be the author of this dissertation/thesis.
\author{Go Bears}
%% This is the name of the .bib files that holds all of your references.
%% It can be a comma separated list if there is more than one file.
\reffile{references.bib}
%
%% These are the names of the .tex files which hold the
%% respective section of the thesis.  If one of these sections
%% is not included, comment out the corresponding line.
\abstract{abstract}
%\acknowledgements{acknowledgements}
%\dedication{dedication}
%\preface{preface}
%
%% Include the chapters.
\newchapter{chapter1}
\newchapter{chapter2}
\newchapter{chapter3}
%\newchapter{chapter3}
%\newchapter{chapter4}

%% Include any appendices.
\newappendix{appendixA}
\newappendix{appendixB}

%% Include any references which should appear in the bibliography,
%% but are not explicitly referenced in the thesis.
%\nocite{re:toolan:as03}

\end{document}
```

Again, pretty straight forward. Chapter 1 says:

```
\chapter{Introduction}
This thesis is an extension to reference 1 where we conduct an analysis of the a study of the 2-Antenna problem, delve a little deeper into the mechanics of the simulations, and present some additional results.
```

This error appears regardless of which chapter I use (some being more complex than chapter 1). I suspect there is something in the document class that is demanding a new line, but I'm not very experienced in Tex. Any ideas?

Thanks for helping!

-DR

Comment: you have presumably used (but not shown here) `\\ ` in the wrong place. It appears to be in `\newchapter` which is a non standard command to which you have not shown the definition.

Comment: @David Carlisle - Thanks for helping. 
inside the document class I found this:

\def\newchapter#1{%
  \if@gotfirstchapter\else
    \@gotfirstchaptertrue
    \initialstuff
  \fi
  \include{#1}
}

But no \\

Comment: That error is only made (in standard classes at least) by `\\ ` or `\newline` so somewhere you must have one of those...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my error:

```
usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
```

was the culprit. Not sure why or how - I'll look into that another day that I haven't wasted 2 hours trying to compile, but removing the declaration removed my errors.

Cheers!

And thanks @David Carlisle for the comments.